# How to iterate over a pandas dataframe to assign values in specific columns to a string

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I'm having problems figuring out the correct code to iterate over a pandas dataframe in order to assign values in specific columns to values in a dictionary.

I used pandas to read csv file to get the df below:

[image: dataframe pic]

```
     badge_id  case_id case_type description  short_des
0    123      1690     type0     subtype4        xxx
1    456      1717     type0     subtype2        yyy
2    789      1389     type0     subtype2        aaa
3    231      1540     type3     subtype1        bbb
```

I would like to iterate over the df to assign values in columns badge_id, case_id, and short_desc to the following string.

```
"{'opened_for': { value: **df[badge_id]**},'short_description': { value : **df['short_desc]**}, 'case_id': { value : **df[case_id]**}}"
```

I tried assigning the data in each column to a variable by appending the data in each column to an empty list. Then I used a for loop to iterate through the rows and list variables, but I can't seem to get the data from all three columns into their own designated strings.

Given the above df, the ideal output is 4 strings (or more depending on how many rows of data there are in the df):

```
"{'opened_for': { value: **'123'**},'short_description': { value : **'xxx'**}, 'case_id': { value : **1690**}}"

"{'opened_for': { value: **'456'**},'short_description': { value : **'yyy'**}, 'case_id': { value : **'1717'**}}"

"{'opened_for': { value: **'789'**},'short_description': { value : **'aaa'**}, 'case_id': { value : **'1389'**}}"

"{'opened_for': { value: **'231'**},'short_description': { value : **'bbb'**}, 'case_id': { value : **'1540'**}}"
```

Comment: PwrSerg, there is any reason why you are using a dict inside other dict?
Do you can use:"{'opened_for': '123', 'short_description': 'xxx',  'case_id': 1690}"?

Comment: Hi @UrantiaThePlayer. Thanks for the question. I'm using a nested dictionary because it will be constructed into a payload to post to an API once I can fix the iteration to pick up the data in each row. The API uses the nested dictionary format so I just have to figure out how to fix the looping to pick up the necessary data from the df.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer! If whatAndrej didn't work, you can try:

for x in range(len(df)):
    new_dict['opened_for'] = {'value': df['badge_id'][x]}
    new_dict['short_description'] = {'value' : df['short_desc'][x]}
    new_dict['case_id'] = {'value' : df['case_id'][x]}
    list_to_fill.append(new_dict.copy())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension + `df.iterrows()`:

```py
out = [
    {
        "opened_for": {"value": row["badge_id"]},
        "short_description": {"value": row["short_des"]},
        "case_id": {"value": row["case_id"]},
    }
    for _, row in df.iterrows()
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "opened_for": {"value": 123},
        "short_description": {"value": "xxx"},
        "case_id": {"value": 1690},
    },
    {
        "opened_for": {"value": 456},
        "short_description": {"value": "yyy"},
        "case_id": {"value": 1717},
    },
    {
        "opened_for": {"value": 789},
        "short_description": {"value": "aaa"},
        "case_id": {"value": 1389},
    },
    {
        "opened_for": {"value": 231},
        "short_description": {"value": "bbb"},
        "case_id": {"value": 1540},
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej! This works perfectly!